# Find points that lie within a set of coordinates

Tags: postgis, sql, point, extents

I have a PostGIS db, and I want to find the points that lie within some region (a bounding box). I have two sets of coordinates, from which I can get all four rectangle points that form the box (if needed). My data column in question is named 'point' and it is also of type point.

- Is there anyway to specify four sets of coordinates (lat/long) and get all the points that lie within the box.
- Or specify two points and let the DB work out the rectangle's corners, and return the points within

Just in case I am not being clear as to what I want to achieve. The equivalent with 'vanilla' sql if I had a lat and long field instead of a point would be:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where lat> xMin AND lat < xMax AND long > yMin and long < yMax
```

**UPDATED EDIT:**

I am trying underdark's solution. At first I didn't have the ST_MakePoint constuctor (now I do) and I still get a very similar error (just on a different character).

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ST_Within(ST_MakePoint(point),GeometryFromText('POLYGON((75 20,80 30,90 22,85 10,75 20))',4326))
```

and I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  function st_makepoint(point) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM triples WHERE ST_Within(ST_MakePoint(point),Ge...
                                          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


********** Error **********

ERROR: function st_makepoint(point) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 39
```

**EDIT:**

In the short term I can solve it with:

```
SELECT * FROM triples WHERE box '((point1),(point2))' @> point
```

But I will have to work out why none of the PostGIS functions are not working for me.

Comment: The preferred method is to post in one place only.  If that place is inappropriate or doesn't work out, it can easily be migrated.  I'm not going to take any action, because GIS is where your question should be, but I would urge you to delete the cross post on SO.

Comment: @whuber .. done.

Comment: Does -- select GeometryFromText('POLYGON((75 20,80 30,90 22,85 10,75 20))',4326) -- work?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I tried a variety of different variations of what you said and they didn't work

Comment: What's the "point" column your referencing in ST_MakePoint(point)

Comment: Yes it works, @Sean.

Comment: It is the column that contains the points that I am trying to get back as the answer to the query.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me I'm new with PostGIS, I think there may be some confusion ... I have spatial (geography coordinates) e.g. "(52.657,-8.66)" so I do I have to use ST_GeographyFromText instead?

Comment: ST_GeographyFromText will assume the your SRID is 4326

Comment: Thanks Mapperz ... very sorry everyone, I think the issue is actually that PostGIS functions are not working at all !!! I started doing a very basic tutorial and got the same error. So I will have to look into this more deeply, it's probably not an issue with any code.

Comment: Btw I am using pgAdmin - is there something you have to do to 'enable' postGIS if you installed it using StackBuilder?

Comment: You should find a database called "postgis_template" if installation using Stackbuilder was successful. This template should be used to create your PostGIS-enabled database.

Comment: Yep. I have template_postgis, I'll work it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
ST_Within(the_geom, GeometryFromText ('POLYGON((75 20,80 30,90 22,85 10,75 20))', 4326))
```

<-- replace coordinates as necessary

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but what is 'the_geom' ... am I supposed to alias the SELECT * FROM myTable query and does that value become 'the_geom'

Comment: Sorry, of course it's the column being searched. I would call it db_column or something like that, but postgis docs think otherwise ... it makes sense when you know what it is.

Comment: When I run this, I am getting an error that says GeometryFromText does not exist. I'm using postgis 2.0. I also tried st_geomfromtext.

Comment: @underdark maybe I'm wrong but it seems that a parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want the BBOX (Bounding Box) from your points - so **ST_Extent** would be favourable.

BBOX2D

http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_extent_expand_buffer_distance.snippet

would provide the http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.htm page but the server is having issues

Comment: re:server ... I know, I've been trying to look at Google's cache copies :)